# How to change my root password on Sequel Pro?

Tags: passwords, mysql

I went to the sequel pro website and tried running the command `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('newpassword');` in a new query when I opened up the app but it gave me a syntax error. After that I decided to try the terminal route. I've logged into sql through the terminal and tried running `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE User='root';` and tried `UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('newpassword') WHERE User='root';` but they both give me this error. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('newpassword') WHERE User='root'' at line 1`. I believe I have the latest version, 8.0.17.

Comment: The error message from MySQL doesn't match the command you've supplied. Could you please supply the responses from `describe mysql.user` and `UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('newpassword') WHERE User='root';`?

Comment: @Joundill I'm not to sure what to put when I entered `describe mysql` (I'm very new) but it gives me an `->` which I'm assuming wants me to enter more stuff in. When I type in `UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('newpassword') WHERE User='root';` this is the error message I get `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('newpassword') WHERE User='root'' at line 1`

Comment: You'll need to put a semicolon at the end of `describe mysql.user`

Comment: @Joundill it listed commands to use but I'm not sure why the commands I've tried running aren't working. Do you know which one could help change my password?

Comment: No, I need a bit more information before I can tell you that.

Can you run `describe mysql.user;` and supply the output please?